# Adding and mounting a NFS share from RPM installer

Tags: yum, rpm, nfs

I am building an installer for a proprietary SW package that requires an NFS mount to be added, if not already present, to /etc/fstab, and then mounted. I would like to automate this if possible so that adding the mount cannot be missed when installing the package, and so that installation will fail if the mount fails. The target machine uses yum.

I could do something like this in my RPM spec file:

```
%post
if grep --quiet --fixed-strings -e "%{MY_MOUNT}" "%{FSTAB}"; then
  echo INFO: mount for xyz already exists
else
  echo "%{MY_MOUNT}" >> "%{FSTAB}"
  mount "%{MOUNT_POINT}"
  echo INFO: added mount for xyz
fi
```

Before rolling this out, I want to make sure this is not a bad practice from a sys admin perspective. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's your software, but why on earth do you require an nfs mount to be in place. It this is going to across the internet then it will fail. Leave it to the sysadmins to configure manually if required. Putting in needless nfs mounts can lead to security issues.

Comment: @Bib - this will only be accessed from my intranet. But to your point, baking the fstab entry into the installer is a risk, e.g. if we need to tweak the mount parameters in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practice. You can check for the existence of a mount point if you insist. But I would never touch fstab from the rpm scriptlet. This is not what a regular sysadmin expected.

I would instead offer a customer Ansible role that installs and configure the software. And you can manipulate the fstab from that role.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful. I made the scriptlet check for the existence of the mount and issue a warning if not present.